# Rendering list in React with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapping

I've got a list to render in React using typescipt approach.

My solution is:

```
import {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


interface AlbumListProps {
  recordData: albumsDataType;
};

type RecordType = {
  id: string;
  createdTime: string;
  fields: {
    Artist: string;
    Title: string;
    Genre: string[];
    Format: string
    PurchaseDate: string
  }
};

type albumsDataType = {
  records: RecordType[];
};



const AlbumList = (props: AlbumListProps) => {
  const { records  } = props.recordData;

  records.map((record) => {
    return <p key={record.id}>{record.fields.Artist}</p>
  })
}

const Collection = () => {
  const testData: albumsDataType = {
  records:[
  {
    id: "rec6jHXMmGsIkXKb8",
    createdTime: "2023-06-12T20:42:28.000Z",
    fields: {
      Artist: "Nick Cave",
      Title: "Murder Ballads",
      Genre: [
        "rec1WLEWT7bFVKyAk"
      ],
      Format: "CD",
      PurchaseDate: "2003-11-11"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "rec6ycqLLe8LVIvJS",
    createdTime: "2023-06-12T21:12:10.000Z",
    fields: {
      Artist: "Cypress Hill",
      Title: "Till Death Do Us Part",
      Genre: [
        "recU45ztU9XMQGShJ"
      ],
      Format: "CD",
      PurchaseDate: "2010-08-01"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "recDfJeV3tCLQDmx8",
    createdTime: "2023-06-12T21:13:29.000Z",
    fields: {
      Artist: "Depeche Mode",
      Title: "Violator",
      Genre: [
        "recKIbSdjSLbP3gk9"
      ],
      Format: "CD",
      PurchaseDate: "2002-07-01"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "recLL4R1Gb48zwZv5",
    createdTime: "2023-06-12T20:42:28.000Z",
    fields: {
      Artist: "Anette Askvik",
      Title: "Liberty",
      Genre: [
        "reczPn3xYhy5U0Rup"
      ],
      Format: "CD",
      PurchaseDate: "2022-11-01"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "recmtg3uEUmTybrqr",
    createdTime: "2023-06-12T20:42:28.000Z",
    fields: {
      Artist: "Nick Cave",
      Title: "Murder Ballads",
      Genre: [
        "rec1WLEWT7bFVKyAk"
      ],
      Format: "LP",
      PurchaseDate: "2022-07-01"
    }
  }
]};

return(
 <div>
  <AlbumList recordData={testData} />
</div>
```

)

```
};

export default Collection;
```

Unfortunately I've got a console error:

'AlbumList' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.

And lint error in VSCode:

'AlbumList' cannot be used as a JSX component.
Its type '(props: AlbumListProps) => void' is not a valid JSX element type.
Type '(props: AlbumListProps) => void' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Well, `AlbumList` indeed doesn't return anything.  Did you mean to use a `return` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `return` somthing from `AlbumList`. So you can return `JSX` as:

[`LIVE DEMO`](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-fermi-w3mmzw?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
const AlbumList = (props: AlbumListProps) => {
  const { records } = props.recordData;

  return (
    <>
      {records.map((record) => {
        return <p key={record.id}>{record.fields.Artist}</p>;
      })}
    </>
  );
};

const Collection = () => {
  const testData: albumsDataType = {
    records: [
      {
        id: "rec6jHXMmGsIkXKb8",
        createdTime: "2023-06-12T20:42:28.000Z",
        fields: {
          Artist: "Nick Cave",
          Title: "Murder Ballads",
          Genre: ["rec1WLEWT7bFVKyAk"],
          Format: "CD",
          PurchaseDate: "2003-11-11"
        }
      },
      {
        id: "rec6ycqLLe8LVIvJS",
        createdTime: "2023-06-12T21:12:10.000Z",
        fields: {
          Artist: "Cypress Hill",
          Title: "Till Death Do Us Part",
          Genre: ["recU45ztU9XMQGShJ"],
          Format: "CD",
          PurchaseDate: "2010-08-01"
        }
      },
      {
        id: "recDfJeV3tCLQDmx8",
        createdTime: "2023-06-12T21:13:29.000Z",
        fields: {
          Artist: "Depeche Mode",
          Title: "Violator",
          Genre: ["recKIbSdjSLbP3gk9"],
          Format: "CD",
          PurchaseDate: "2002-07-01"
        }
      },
      {
        id: "recLL4R1Gb48zwZv5",
        createdTime: "2023-06-12T20:42:28.000Z",
        fields: {
          Artist: "Anette Askvik",
          Title: "Liberty",
          Genre: ["reczPn3xYhy5U0Rup"],
          Format: "CD",
          PurchaseDate: "2022-11-01"
        }
      },
      {
        id: "recmtg3uEUmTybrqr",
        createdTime: "2023-06-12T20:42:28.000Z",
        fields: {
          Artist: "Nick Cave",
          Title: "Murder Ballads",
          Genre: ["rec1WLEWT7bFVKyAk"],
          Format: "LP",
          PurchaseDate: "2022-07-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <AlbumList recordData={testData} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Collection;
```